# Django database construction clients-products

Tags: database, django

I have to build a database with clients and products. The problem is that i should have two types of clients: individuals and companies. I don't get the philosophy for starting the project and some guidelines would be great!

How can i construct the database or the queries to link products to a specific type of client?

Should i make a third clients table and link individuals and companies tables to this table and the products table also linked to this third table or should i have 2 tables for individuals and companies and a flag inside both like "is individual" and "is company"?

When i generate the form to enter a new client i should first select the type of client and based on that a specific form for individuals or company should appear.

Is it a better way to construct that type of client-products database? If i kinda join the two types of clients into just 1 table (an individual have approximatly the same characteristic as a company) it's easy.

Thank you very much!